# Is this code an example of encapsulation?

Tags: c#

I create private method, with different input data, it works differently.

```
private void SetSelectedRouters(bool isSelected)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_listPlatforms.Count; i++)
    {
             m_listPlatforms[i].IsCheked = isSelected;
    }
}
```

And create public method for interaction.

```
public void SelectedAllRouters()
{
    SetSelectedRouters(true);
}
public void SelectedNoneRouters()
{
    SetSelectedRouters(false);
}
```

I think this is encapsulation, or as something in a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't encapsulation. It's an [extracted method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html). All of the code in the method is relevant to one other and its purpose is clearly described in its name. This is also called a [helper method](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs132/Patterns/pat_HelperMethod.html).

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's more code reuse, extracting the common functionality within two methods so that those methods become trivial, simply calling a common method.

(I'd encourage you to use `foreach` to improve the readability further, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia claims:

In a programming language encapsulation is used to refer to one of two related but distinct notions, and sometimes to the combination[1][2] thereof:

*1. A language mechanism for restricting access to some of the object's components.*

*2. A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data.*

So to me it seems yes (by looking at second point)